# SSRS 2005 Report layout displaying on Report Server differently than in VS preview

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I created a simple SSRS 2005 report.  It is a table with 2 columns. When I preview the report it looks great.  I put it on the Report Server (Report Manager) and when it is displayed the width of the columns of the table are only as wide as the widest value.  I want the column widths to be a fixed width.  I also want the rows to have alternating colors.  On the Report Server, only the 2nd column has the coloring.

I have tried setting the table column attribute 'CanGrow' to true.  But the table is only as wide as the data.  The column widths are set to 3.09167in and 3.55.

It seems that I cannot widen the table columns from their original widths.

If I add padding to the left and right margins the column data is wider but the row coloring is still incorrect.

Has anybody seen this problem before?

**Update**
Below are screen shots of what the report looks like when previewed in VS2005 and when it is displayed on the Report Server.

In Visual Studio it looks like this (which is what I want it to look like.)
[image]

This is what it looks like on the Report Manager:

[image]

This is the code that I use to alternate the row color on both columns but only the second one displays the green color:

```
= IIf(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2 = 0, "#BCDCBC", "Transparent")
```

If I add a third column, the alternating color works for the third column also but not for the first column.

Comment: Can you provide any example images of the design layout, and what is the expression you are using for the row coloring?

Comment: During your preview try to select 'Print Layout' so you can see its actual print out during print see this image http://prntscr.com/9dybmy because there are times that using preview only the alignments is not the same compare to the actual print-out.

Comment: I don't have a 'Print Layout' option when I am view the report from the 'Preview' tab.  This is Visual Studio 2005.  Maybe that option is in a later version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody else has this problem this is how I worked around it...

To solve the report width problem I put the table inside a rectangle and made the rectangle the width I wanted the table to be and that was corrected.

I could not figure out why the alternating row color code would not work for the first column but for all others.  So, I added a 'hack'.  I added an additional column to be the first column with no heading and no data.  Made it very small in width (0.03) so that is not too noticeable.  That allowed the other columns to be correctly colored and the first one is not.